# Typed default arguments in destructuring parameters

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.0

One of my favorite features of es6 is the ability to use destructuring parameters.
For example:

```
function example1({
    bar = -1,
    transform = Math.abs
} = {}) {
    transform(bar);
}
```

However, the typescript compiler generates **an error** when an explicit type needs to be assigned to one of the arguments (e.g. to give it greater flexibility than would be inferred by the default):

```
type Formatter = { (n: number): (number | string) };

function example2({
    bar = -1,
    transform: Formatter = Math.abs 
} = {}) {
    // ERROR: cannot find name 'transform'
    return transform(bar) + ' is the value';
}
```

The only way around this I've found is to explicitly type the whole set of parameters - which seems overly complex when the remaining parameter types can be inferred:

```
type Formatter = { (n: number): (number | string) };
type ExampleOpts = {
    bar?: number,
    transform?: Formatter
};

function example3({
    bar = -1,
    transform= Math.abs 
}: ExampleOpts = {}) {
    return transform(bar) + ' is the value';
}
```

Thoughts? Is there are syntax that accomplishes #3 with the simplicity of #2 that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type Formatter = { (n: number): (number | string) };

function example2({
    bar = -1,
    transform = Math.abs as Formatter 
} = {}) {
    // ERROR: cannot find name 'transform'
    return transform(bar) + ' is the value';
}
```

When using default parameters, you are aiming for type inference. If there's no type definition or you'd like to provide your own, simply cast it with the 'variable as type' syntax! :)

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought about the ability of type coercion to broaden a type - usually I've seen it used to narrow the type. Also, there is a related issue in that destructuring parameters can't contain any typed parameters without default values (required or optional) - at least without explicit typing as in `example3`.